# Elasticsearch head plugin not working through nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, elasticsearch, reverse-proxy, elasticsearch-plugin

I have elasticsearch with the head plugin installed running on a different server. I also set up an nginx reverse proxy for my ES instance. The configuration looks like below:

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
      listen       80;
      server_name  es.mydomain.net;
      location / {
          proxy_set_header    Host $http_host;
          proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

          proxy_redirect off;
          proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:9200;
      }
    }
}
```

Hitting the link `http://es.mydomain.net/` works fine and I get a status 200 response. However, if I try to hit the link `http://es.mydomain.net/_plugin/head/`, I seemingly get a blank page. Note, the page loads fine if I access the head plug-in directly without the reverse proxy, via `http://SERVERIP:PORT/_plugin/head/`.

EDIT:

After doing some more debugging, I saw a `net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH` error in the console for the page. After looking at nginx's log, to see what the error was, I came upon the true culprit, which is this error:

```
2015/05/27 16:26:48 [crit] 29765#0: *655 open() "/home/web/nginx/proxy_temp/6/0
0/0000000006" failed (13: Permission denied) while reading upstream, client: 10.
183.6.63, server: es.mydomain.com, request: "GET /_plugin/head/dist/app.js HTT
P/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9200/_plugin/head/dist/app.js", host: "es.my
domain.com", referrer: "http://es.mydomain.com/_plugin/head/"
```

I googled this one particularly, and it seems this can happen because the worker process is `nobody`, and the folder it is trying to read/write to may not have the right permissions. Still looking into this, but will update with an answer when found

*EDIT 2*: Removed unnecessary information to make issue more direct.

Comment: Are you sure that nginx proxies all subpaths, i.e., "/_plugin/*" as well? It seems that you only proxy the root path.

Comment: @Zouzias I updated the OP with some more info. I've added the actual error that's occurring. Seems to be a permission issue.

Comment: Take a look at this article, it might be helpful, i.e., set proxy_http_version 1.1 https://www.elastic.co/blog/playing-http-tricks-nginx

Comment: Thanks for the link, and it is something I've already looked at. I was able to figure out a solution, and I've posted it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to work out two solutions to get around the permission, so I'll present them both.

One thing to know about my nginx set-up is that I did not use sudo to install it. I unarchived the tar file, configured, and make installed it, so it was residing in /home/USERNAME/nginx/.

The issue was that starting nginx was creating a worker process under "nobody", which was then trying to read/write in /home/USERNAME/nginx/proxy_temp/, which it did not have permission to do. Solutions on the web said to just `chown nobody` to the temp folders, but this solution wasn't really appropriate in my particular case since we were inside USERNAME's home.

## Solution 1:

Add `user USERNAME;` to top of nginx.conf, so that it would run the worker process as the specified username. This no longer led to a permission issue, as USERNAME had the permissions to read/write in the desired temp folders.

## Solution 2:

Add proxy_temp_path to the server config. With this, you could specify a folder for the nobody process to create where it would have read/write permission. Note, you might still run into permission issues if the other *_temp folders are used by your nginx server.

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  es.mydomain.net;
  location / {
      proxy_set_header    Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:9200;
      proxy_temp_path /foo/bar/proxy_temp

  }
}
```

I personally preferred solution 1, as it would apply to all the server blocks, and I would not have to worry about the other *_temp folders once the conf file got more complex.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the plugin head on all ES nodes.